# Closed question that needs to be edited

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, editing

This question...

[Family visitor visa refused, should I apply for dependent visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38137/family-visitor-visa-rejected-should-i-apply-for-dependent-visa?rq=1)

needs its title corrected.  But the question has been closed and so is off limits to would-be editors.  Raising a flag gets a return value of 'helpful', but nothing happens.

How to edit a closed question?

Comment: The question can be edited by >2k rep users and the author, I think, regardless if it's closer or open.

Comment: I see the flags were handled twice with a "helpful" closure. (but the title was also edited by someone with >2k rep)

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee, yes, that was Joe, see below.  The corrections to the question have been made and all's well with the world now.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee It seems you won the right to mark this one too as status-completed. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to edit the question as you suggested. I added the `refusal` keywords where applicable. If indeed you have issues with editing closed question, it might be worthy to contact SE staff or post on Meta.SE.

Comment: Thanks, now TSE is in sync front to back, top to bottom